# Improve audio recording volume using Audacity

Tags: audio, audacity

I have an audio recording in .amr format. The audio is around 40-45 minutes long. I have two persons voice recorded in it. The recorder was nearer to one person than the other. I would like to make all the peeks and lows same in order to hear the audio of the other person away from the recorder louder. I need to improve the entire track,correcting all lows at once. How can i do it using audacity..? or do specify if any other tool is good at this thing.

Comment: i dont think there is a way.

Answer (score 0):

Look for 'compressor' or 'limiter' in the plugins/tools [I don't use Audacity so idk where you'll find it, but I have no doubt there will be one]

A comp/lim will allow you to keep the volume of the loudest parts similar, whilst raising the quieter passages. The result may be noisy, as it will increase the background noise too, but ought to be acceptable enough to hear what was said.